# RedirectToAction inside a method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this question is kinda stupid, but can i actually redirect to specific page inside a method?

**The Method**

```
public void CheckAdminPrivilege()
{

    if (some if statement)
    {

        //the redirect wont work
        RedirectToAction("someAction", "someController");

    }
}
```

**Controller that call the method**

```
public ActionResult CreateAdmin()
{           
    //this one wont redirect
    CheckAdminPrivilege();


    //SOME OTHER CODE

    return View();
}
```

when i call the CreateAdmin ActionResult, the CheckAdminPriviledge method is running, but the RedirectToAction is not running. is there any other way to use redirect??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a good work around as shown :

**The Method**

```
public bool CheckAdminPrivilege()
{  
    if (some if statement)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    { 
       return false; 
    }
}
```

**Controller that call the method**

```
 public ActionResult CreateAdmin()
 {   
    bool token;        
    token = CheckAdminPrivilege();
    if(token == true)
    { return RedirectToAction("someAction", "someController"); }

    //SOME OTHER CODE

    return View();
 }
```

---

**OR Try This :**

**The Method**

```
public ActionResult CheckAdminPrivilege()
{  
    if (some if statement)
    {
      return RedirectToAction("someAction", "someController");
    }
      return null;
}
```

**Controller that call the method**

```
public ActionResult CreateAdmin()
{   
    CheckAdminPrivilege();

    //SOME OTHER CODE

    return View();
}
```

**Just a piece of advice i think with `CheckAdminPrivilege` method you are checking that a user has admin privilege or not for this purpose instead of making a method just make a custom action filter,if want to know more about custom action filter see [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) and [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=976)**

Comment: nice suggestion :D, but if there are 2 or more if statement let just say first if return "1" and second if return "2", what method type should i use?

Comment: sorry i've tried to make my own method, but overall my question is already answered, i'm gonna post my method version after i test it... Thx @Exception :D